# Function is not getting compiled oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am creating a function that returns a table in Oracle and when I am compiling it is showing error:

```
Error line:
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type.
```

This is my function:

```
Create function fn_list(BU number, DU number) return t_table
is
  rec t_table
begin
  /*more codes are here*/
  rec:= t_type(1,1,2)
  return rec;/*error is here*/
end;
end fn_list;

create type t_type is object(ID number,BU number, DU number);

create type t_table is table of t_type;
```

Comment: Post your complete code, this one looks incorrect at many places.

Comment: @PankajKumar: You are creating custom type t_type with three NUMBER only. In your cord you are trying to create it with 4 NUMBERS(1,1,2,3).

Comment: In addition to what Sudipta has said, please post a cut-down version of your function that replicates your issue. Most of the time, by trying to produce the simplest test case that demonstrates the issue, you can spot where the issue is occurring. Even if you don't manage to spot it yourself, a simple and complete test case allows the rest of us to run the code and help you spot the issue.

Comment: Missing semicolon after `rec t_table`. What is `rec: t_type(1,1,2,3)` supposed to do? `return rec:` ends with a colon; should this be a semicolon? What does `end;` end?

Comment: two typos I removed thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
create type t_type is object(ID number,BU number, DU number);
/
create type t_table is table of t_type;
/
Create function fn_list(BU number, DU number) return t_table
is
  rec t_type;
  tab t_table;
begin
  /*more codes are here*/
  rec:= t_type(1,1,2);
  tab := new t_table();
  tab.extend;
  tab(tab.last) := rec;
  return tab;
end fn_list;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns a `t_table` type but you are trying to return a `t_type` type. You also have an extra `END` statement and several missing semi-colons.

You can correct it and simplify it to:

```
Create function fn_list(BU number, DU number) return t_table
is
begin
  return t_table( t_type(1,1,2) );
end fn_list;
/
```